# Unreachable code detected in Switch

Tags: c#, asp.net, switch-statement, compiler-warnings, unreachable-code

I am using a switch and get a warning that code is unreachable.

[image: Switch warning]

If control goes to case 2 or 3, something will get execute then what is the issue?

Comment: The control flow will never reach the `break` statement, because of the `gotos`

Comment: Somethings from either if or else will be executed, but as you are using goto in both the block, code will never reach to break statement, and that's the reason it's showing unreachable code message.

Comment: As it says, that break operation is unreachable. So you can remove that line.

Comment: Do you really need a switch statement here at all? that maze of goto's makes it look like you just need to refine the logic into if statements

Comment: The issue is that no matter what happen, that line is never going to be hit, because you are altering the execution flow

Answer (score 2):

While executing `case "2"` and `case "3"`, your function pointer will never reach `break` statement because of `goto` statements in `if..else` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

It is unreachable, the if statement above it will always redirect with the `gotos`.

You could just refactor the logic into a simple if statement..

```
var cemValIsOne = hdnCEMStatus.Value == "1";
var cemIDIsZeroOrEmpty = hdmCEMID.Value == "" || hdmCEMID.Value == "0";
if(cemValIsOne || (!cemValIsOne && !cemIDIsZeroOrEmpty))
{
     // case 1 code...
}
else
{
    // case 0 true if statement code
}
```